# When do assets get loaded into video memory?

Tags: level-design, memory

Specifically when do textures / geometry load into video memory? Do objects need to be in a direct line of sight (on screen) or are they drawn in at a certain camera radius?

Obviously thing like mipmaps and LODs are progressively loaded depending on camera position, but will those assets occupy video memory if they are say within camera radius but behind a wall off 'screen space'?

Comment: Which technology is this question about?

Comment: This is too broad to answer. "It depends." Voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

You question is very broad. This is very dependent on the platform you are using and the framework/engine if any. The answer is most likely: They are loaded into video memory when your code/framework/engine load them there.

Your other question is related to culling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination#Culling_and_VSD

The assets are most likely to be loaded to (asset, video) memory, but not rendered. But again, it is platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

They endup in video memory when you create the resource for it. And if you run out of video memory it will be paged to the RAM, and if you run out of ram you will page it to the Harddrive, and if you run out of that.. i dont really know whats happening.

And lets say you run out of videomemory, it will be redirected to the video memory when you are binding or using that geometry/texture/uav what ever.
this is also a bit depending on how you create the resource, for instance in dx11, there is plenty of resource flags that will tell you where it will endup.

Mipmaps, are a part of the texture so they will be "living" with the texture it self. so they are not sepparate.

Comment: When your page file on the HDD gets full, it results in a crash or a freeze until you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if you're using a game engine or not. If not, things are only loaded into memory when you load them into memory.

For example, in a 2D tile based game, you could easily render only the visible tiles. Anything outside of the visible tiles is never rendered.

What is loaded into memory? Anything and everything, or nothing at all. If it's rendered, it's in memory. However, you can easily load tons of things in memory that are never rendered, so always remember that you need to handle both memory management AND rendering management to avoid loading, keeping, and rendering that which one cannot see.

Of course, sometimes you WANT to load something in when it isn't rendered, so it is accessed faster.